# Htaccess redirect all endpoints except first

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have API and UI on same domain. Now I have redirected all calls to UI (`index.hmtl`). I need to add redirect all requirements after first `/` to another file (`index.php`).

`https://app.domain.com/customer-name/?t=View/Invoice` -> `/index.html`

`https://app.domain.com/customer-name/this-is-api-call/`  -> `/api/api.php`

`https://app.domain.com/customer-name/another-api-call/with/levels`  -> `/api/api.php`

`'customer-name'` in example is variable, not fixed.

My current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: _“My current .htaccess:”_ - in other words - you have not even _tried_ anything yet?

Comment: So by what pattern are your non-API-call URL you have shown, and the other two, differentiable? Is anything that has something in the path after the customer name supposed to be an API call? (That is a bad URL structure you have gone here for to begin with, IMHO.)

Comment: @CBroe UI start with this pattern "/anything/?t=" and all other calls is API.

Comment: Checking the query string content will require another RewriteCond. Suggest you go research how that basically works, then try something - and then report back here. (So far, this question does not give the impression that you actually put much effort into this so far, so that’s all I am going to give you for now.)